# Backbone model fetch return blank JSON,model dont trigger change event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

when the model fetch from server and return a blank JSON ( `[]`),the model did not change its attribute,so how can I know if the model is return same data , or return blank data?

Answer (score 0):

You can set callback function in `.fetch()` options so you will know when request will finished.
Or you can extend fetch method or add another one with functional you want/need.